# Numerical methods, show that wave equation expression is constant

Tags: numerical-methods, recursion, boundary-value-problem, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

$\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand{\IR}{\Bbb R}\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$
The wave equation:
$$
\pd{^2u}{t^2}(x,t)=c^2\pd{^2u}{x^2}(x,t),~~ t>0,~x\in(0,1)\tag4
$$
[Given wave equation with start and end values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNOtb.png)

where $c$ is constant (sound / light speed), can be approximated in two steps:

- define the vector $u(t) ∈ \IR^{N + 1}$,
  $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$, where $\bar u_j(t) ≃ u(j/N, t)$ for $j = 0,1,2, ..., N$ and let 
  $$
  N^2  (\bar u_{j+1}(t) −2\bar u_{j}(t) + \bar u_{j-1}(t) ) ≃ \pd{^2 u(j / N, t)}{x^2}
  $$ be the usual approximation of the second derivative. Then we get the following system of differential equations (image 2):
  $$
  \frac{\dd^2\bar u_j(t)}{\dd t^2}=c^2N^2  (\bar u_{j+1}(t) −2\bar u_{j}(t) + \bar u_{j-1}(t) ), ~~ j=1,...,N-1,\tag5
  $$
  [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv9Rt.png)

so that $\frac{\dd^2 \hat u(t)}{\dd t^2} = c^2 A \hat u(t)$ where $u(t) ∈ \IR^{N − 1}$ is the vector with the components $\hat u_j(t)=\bar u_j(t)$, $j = 1,..., N-1$ [vector kompenents expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3OyB.png) and $A$ are the $(N −1) × (N −1)$ matrix with $−2N^2$ in the diagonal and $N^2$ in the upper and lower diagonals.

Show that the energy $(|\frac{\dd\hat u(t)}{\dd t}|^2)/2 - c^2\hat u(t) · A\hat u(t)/2$ is constant for all times, where "$·$" means $N-1$ scalar product in $\IR^{N − 1}$. Suggest a suitable numerical method.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a second order equation of the form $\ddot x=f(x)$. You can apply any method that is developed especially for this case like [Numerov's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method)[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3074395/115115), [Beeman's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Beeman%27s_algorithm#Beeman,_1976) or more modern methods that are found in molecular dynamics simulations.

Given that you have an energy function that can serve as Hamiltonian of the equation, you can also use any [symplectic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator), most famously the Verlet second order method, its 4th order modification or the Ruth methods.

Or you could transform the second order system into a first order system of twice the size and apply any ODE solver a là method-of-lines.